# getBars getting called recursively infinite times in the JS API for trading view charting library when select the M interval

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

The provided code functions well for weekly (w), daily (d), and other time frames. However, when the "M" interval (monthly) is selected, the getBars function is continuously called repeatedly. I understand I need to define the from, to, and countBack properties to handle this issue, but I am unsure where to define and stop the repeated calls to `getBars`.

**The code and data file are attached for reference.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TradingView Charting Library example</title>
  <script src="charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library/charting_library.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0px;">
  <!-- A container for the Charting Library widget -->
  <div id="tv_chart_container">
  </div>
</body>
<script>


  const configurationData = {
    supported_resolutions: ['D', 'W', 'M'],
  };

  async function getAllSymbols() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/technicalChart/exchange.php`);
      const jsonData = await response.json();
      const data = Array.isArray(jsonData) ? jsonData : [jsonData]
      let allSymbols = [];
      const symbols = data.map(item => {
        return {
          symbol: item.symbol,
          full_name: item.full_name,
          description: item.description,
          exchange: item.exchange,
          type: item.type,
          stock_name: item.stock_name,
        };
      });
      allSymbols = [...allSymbols, ...symbols];
      return allSymbols;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Symbol Information is not available: ${error}`);
    }
  }


  const datafeed = {
    onReady: (callback) => {
      console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
      setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData));
    },

    searchSymbols: async (
      userInput,
      exchange,
      symbolType,
      onResultReadyCallback
    ) => {

      console.log('[searchSymbols]: Method call');
      const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
      const newSymbols = symbols.filter(symbol => {
        const isExchangeValid = exchange === '' || symbol.exchange === exchange;
        const isFullSymbolContainsInput = symbol.full_name
          .toLowerCase()
          .indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        return isExchangeValid && isFullSymbolContainsInput;
      });
      onResultReadyCallback(newSymbols);
    },

    resolveSymbol: async (
      symbolName,
      onSymbolResolvedCallback,
      onResolveErrorCallback,
      extension
    ) => {
      const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
      const symbolItem = symbols.find(({ full_name }) => full_name === symbolName);
      if (!symbolItem) {
        onResolveErrorCallback('Cannot resolve symbol');
        return;
      }
      // Symbol information object
      const symbolInfo = {
        ticker: symbolItem.full_name,
        name: symbolItem.symbol,
        description: symbolItem.description,
        type: symbolItem.type,
        session: '24x7',
        timezone: 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
        //exchange: symbolItem.exchange,
        exchange: symbolItem.stock_name,

        minmov: 1,
        pricescale: 100,
        has_intraday: false,
        //has_no_volume: false,
        has_weekly_and_monthly: false,
        supported_resolutions: configurationData.supported_resolutions,
        volume_precision: 2,
        //data_status: 'streaming',
      };
      onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
    },

    getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
      const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
      try {

        const response = await fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/technicalChart/histoday.php?symbol=${symbolInfo.full_name}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
        let bars = [];
        const bar = data.map(item => {
          return {
            time: item.time,
            low: item.low,
            high: item.high,
            open: item.open,
            close: item.close,
            volume: item.volume,
          };
        });
        bars = [...bars, ...bar];
        onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('[getBars]: Get error', error);
        onErrorCallback(error);
      }
    },

    subscribeBars: (symbolInfo, resolution, onRealtimeCallback, subscriberUID, onResetCacheNeededCallback) => {
      console.log('[subscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
    },
    unsubscribeBars: (subscriberUID) => {
      console.log('[unsubscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
    },
  };


  function initOnReady() {

    var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
      symbol: 'POL',            // Default symbol pair
      interval: 'D',                        // Default interval
      fullscreen: true,                      // Displays the chart in the fullscreen mode
      container: 'tv_chart_container',       // Reference to an attribute of a DOM element
      datafeed: datafeed,

      library_path: 'charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library/',
      timezone: 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
      drawings_access: { type: 'black', tools: [{ name: "Regression Trend" }] },
      disabled_features: ["volume_force_overlay", "study_templates"],
      overrides: {
        "volumePaneSize": "medium",
        "mainSeriesProperties.style": 1,
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor": "#00e100",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.downColor": "#ff0000",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderColor": "#666666",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderUpColor": "#666666",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderDownColor": "#666666",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickUpColor": "#666666",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickDownColor": "#666666",
        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickColor": "#666666"
      },
      enabled_features: ["context_menus", "pane_context_menu", "items_favoriting", "use_localstorage_for_settings", "side_toolbar_in_fullscreen_mode"],
      favorites: {
        intervals: ["1D", "1W", "1M"],
        chartTypes: ["Candles", "Line", "Heiken Ashi"]

      },
      time_frames: [
        { text: '10y', resolution: 'W', description: '10 Year' },
        { text: '5Y', resolution: 'W', description: '5 year' },
        { text: '1Y', resolution: 'D', description: '1 year' },
        { text: '6M', resolution: 'D', description: '6 month' },

      ],


    });


    widget.headerReady().then(function () {
      function createHeaderButton(text, title, clickHandler, options) {
        var button = widget.createButton(options);
        button.setAttribute('title', title);
        button.textContent = text;
        button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        if (text === '+') {
          button.textContent += ' Compare';
        }
      }
      createHeaderButton('Clear Marks', '', function () {
        widget.chart().clearMarks();
      });

      createHeaderButton('Load Marks', '', function () {
        widget.chart().refreshMarks();
      });
      createHeaderButton('Remove All Studies', '', function () {
        widget.chart().removeAllStudies();
      });

      createHeaderButton('Remove All Shapes', '', function () {
        widget.chart().removeAllShapes();
      });


    });

  };

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initOnReady, false);


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**history.php returns row format around**

```json
[
  {
      "time": 1074452400000,
      "open": 227.5,
      "high": 229.5,
      "low": 220.5,
      "close": 221.05,
      "volume": 8092200
  },
  {
      "time": 1074538800000,
      "open": 221.05,
      "high": 223,
      "low": 219.25,
      "close": 221.9,
      "volume": 6180700
  },
...
```

**exchange.php returns row format around**

```json
[
  {
      "symbol": "AABS",
      "full_name": "AABS",
      "description": "Al-Abbas Sugar Mills Ltd",
      "exchange": "Pakistan Stock Exchange",
      "type": "Stock",
      "stock_name": "PSX"
  },
  {
      "symbol": "POWER",
      "full_name": "POWER",
      "description": "Power Cement Ltd",
      "exchange": "Pakistan Stock Exchange",
      "type": "Stock",
      "stock_name": "PSX"
  }
...
```

Comment: I submitted this request on 24 July 2023. Please help me to resolve my issue. Waiting for any expert person help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've made modifications to the attached code for the "getbars" function. Additionally, I've adjusted the query within "histoday1.php" by incorporating the condition "trandate <= toTs." in the data query. This alteration successfully prevents the occurrence of an infinite "getbar" function call.

```
getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
    const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
    var exchange ="PSX"
    const urlParameters = {
        e: exchange,
        fsym: symbolInfo.full_name,
        tsym: symbolInfo.full_name,
        toTs: to,
        limit: 4819,
    };
    const query = Object.keys(urlParameters)
        .map(name => `${name}=${encodeURIComponent(urlParameters[name])}`)
            .join('&');
    try {
        
        const response = await fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/technicalChart/histoday1.php?${query}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        let bars = [];
        const bar = data.map(item => {
            return {
                time: item.time,
                low: item.low,
                high: item.high,
                open: item.open,
                close: item.close,
                volume: item.volume,
            };
        });
        bars = [...bars, ...bar];
        onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    } catch (error) {
        onErrorCallback(error);
    }
}
```